# How to change size of Zone 2

Tags: web-part-zone

I'm trying to change the size of Zone 2 to fit next to Zone 1 on a SharePoint page. Right now, Zone 1 is left on the top of the page and Zone 2 on the right side at the bottom of page. I need both the zones next to each other on the top of page. How to move Zone 2 up?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have this open in SharePoint Designer, go to the Code view and look for the HTML Table that surrounds the web part zones (scan the code for `WebPartZone` elements). You'll notice the width of the `<TD>` elements that surround the webpartzones has percentage widths. Try altering these and flipping back to the Layout view to see how it changes. By default I think they are split 60%/40% but padding might be pushing one of the two to become too big.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is for a blog page--Zone 1--Navigation. I made the width smaller and it added a horizontal and vertical scrollbar. But I only want the vertical scrollbar. Do you know how I can make the horizontal disappear????